# How to access PageData in a WebMatrix C# file?

Tags: c#, webmatrix

Many of the WebMatrix examples and tutorials use PageData to transfer data between pages during the page construction process (e.g. between the content page and the layout page).
For example...

```
@{
    Layout = "/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    PageData["Title"] = "Passing Data";
    PageData["TraceData"] += "Start of the main page.|";
}
```

This works fine for simple situations, but I now have enough repeated code using PageData that I want to refactor it into some C# classes.  However in none of the examples or documentation that I have been able to find, are there any "using" statements, or any other context to indicate what object PageData is (or is a property of). In a cshtml file it's "just there" by some magic that I have not yet been able to determine.

How can I get access to PageData in a C# class?  For example, I would like to be able do something like this...

```
public static class MyTrace
{
    public static void Add(string aMessage) {
        PageData["TraceData"] += aMessage + "|";
    }

    public static string Read() {
        return PageData["TraceData"];
    }
}
```

(Please note: This tracing example does not represent the full extent of my usage, but is just a simple example to demonstrate the point.  If there are better ways to implement a tracing system in WebMatrix, then while I would also like to find out about that, it is not the point of this question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the `PageData` property, try the following code:

```
WebPageContext.Current.PagaData
```

The `WebPageContext` type is available in the `System.Web.WebPages` namespace.

Comment: Thanks.  This work well, at least most of the time.

There is one exception I have found - when called from a _PageStart.cshtml file.  In this case the PageData access seems to work, but it must be to some other copy of PageData, because the added data is not visible outside of the _PageStart page.  I'm still a bit confused by this, but I can work around it.